# WP advanced custom field loop showing only one field instead of two

Tags: php

I'm using the ACF WordPress plugin but my php is not working right. I'm using it for testimonials. It is suppose to look like this:

[image]

I'm almost there but what is happening is that is showing **only one** testimonial on **each loop** instead of **two**. This is my php:

```
<ul class="orbit-container">

        <?php
          $count = 0;
          while (have_rows('testimonials')) {
              the_row();

                $image = get_sub_field('avatar');
              $content = get_sub_field('content');
                 $name = get_sub_field('name');

              if ($count > 0 && ($count % 2 == 0)) {
          ?>

          <?php } ?>

          <li class="orbit-slide is-active">
            <div class="bubble">
              <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Testimonials" />
              <?php echo $content; ?>
              <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
            </div>
          </li>

          <?php $count++; }?>   

      </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show how `have_rows()` and `get_sub_field()` are being defined?

Answer (score 0):

I added an `if` and moved around the html tags because they were in the wrong places. It looks like this now:

```
<div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Testimonials" data-orbit>
    <?php 
      if (have_rows('testimonials')) { $count = 0; ?>
      <ul class="orbit-container">

        <?php while(have_rows('testimonials')) { 
          the_row();

          $image = get_sub_field('avatar');
          $content = get_sub_field('content');
          $name = get_sub_field('name');

          if ($count % 2 == 0) {
          ?>

          <li class="orbit-slide">
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="bubble">
              <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Testimonials" />
              <?php echo $content; ?>
              <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>
            </div>

            <?php $count++; } ?>
          </li>

      </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```